# how to set excel cell to 2 decimal places using phpexcel

Tags: phpexcel

```
while ($input = $data_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
$row++;
$letter2 = "A";

 $row++;
    $letter2 = "A";

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($letter2++.$row, $input['emp_loan_code']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($letter2++.$row, $input['date_from']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($letter2++.$row, $input['date_to']);

    if ($input['status'] == 0) {
        $input['status'] = 'Pending';
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($letter2++.$row, $input['status']);
    }
    elseif ($input['status'] == 1) {
        $input['status'] = 'Paid';
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($letter2++.$row, $input['status']);
    }
    elseif ($input['status'] == 2) {
        $input['status'] = 'Cancel';
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($letter2++.$row, $input['status']);
    }
    else{
        $input['status'] = 'Request';
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($letter2++.$row, $input['status']);
    }

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($letter2.$row, $input['amount'])->getStyle()->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0.00');

}
```

i want to set the entire E column to be 2 decimal places and
i already set it to 2 decimal buy the output is still 00.00000

how can i display the output 00.00 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using this:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($letter2.$row, $input['amount'])->getStyle()->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0.00');
```

Try this:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($letter2.$row, number_format($input['amount'],2,'.',''));
```